# 555 Timer 74LS192 IC Circuit

Tags: led, timer

Our instructor gave us the assignment of creating a working schematic using a 555 Timer and a 74LS192 IC using 9 LEDs. The 9 LEDs will blink counting in seconds particularly 9 seconds then it's going to loop from the beginning to start the counting again.

The instructor is not teaching us how to understand the pin configurations of the 2 ICs and I've been searching around the net but haven't found anything.

The parts would be:

- A number of resistors if need be
- A single or more capacitor if need be.
- 1 555 timer
- 1 74LS192 IC
- 9 LEDs

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried reading the data sheet? in electronics, they are your best friend.

Comment: I've tidied the formatting a bit but one reason homework question often "end badly" is when they don't show any attempt to solve it yourself. As echad said look at the datasheets and have a go at a schematic of a 555 and 74LS192 connected together. Even if you get a few things wrong it's likely to come across better and at least show you've made an effort.

Comment: This is for your own good actually. Once you get a job, you're going to need to learn how to do this on your own. You might even need knowledge like this to even pass the interview...

Answer (score 3):

Although it will be difficult for you initially; your professor is doing you a favor by forcing you to read the datasheets. However, since you are probably not accustomed (I admit, I'm not ideal at reading them) to going through datasheets, I'll try to guide you through some logic:

Let's first look at the 74LS192; a quick google search will yield the datasheet on the first hit: [74LS192](http://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS192.shtml)

Interesting, it's a decade counter; but what is a decade counter? Indeed, we must read more to understand. A couple pages down and we find a logic table:
[image]

It appears, that there is a count up mode. That "counts up" on Q0-Q3 outputs given a rising clock edge... could this be useful to us?

So we have some knowledge about that chip; what about the 555 timer?

A google search for "555 Timer datasheet" once again proves reliable: [555 Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf)

On the first page there are applications for the 555:

[image]

Well it sure seems as though this chip is pretty useful! We do require a clock for the 74LS192. I wonder if this 555 can accomplish this for us...

Anyway, that's about as much hints I feel like giving you. Best of luck sir!

Comment: +1 for not over-solving it for the OP :-)

Comment: right .... good to know ur experts. but tnx anyways ... i was able to have a better understanding taught to me from another forum. but tnx for the effort.